# What exactly is "Tensorflow Distibuted", now that we have Tensorflow Serving?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I don't understand why "Tensorflow Distributed" still exists, now that we have Tensorflow Serving.  It seems to be some way to use core Tensorflow as a serving platform, but why would we want that when Tensorflow Serving and TFX is a much more robust platform?  Is it just legacy support?  If so, then the Tensorflow Distributed pages should make that clear and point people towards TFX.

Comment: Well, I don't see a coding related problem here, do you?

Answer (score 1):

Distributed Tensorflow can support training one model in many machines by implementing a parameter server, with either data parallelism or model parallelism.